# Can font size be disabled in QFontDialog::getFont()?

Tags: qt, fonts

I want to allow users to pick a font but the size they choose will have no effect. So it would be best to have that part of the dialog disabled. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Think twice before you try to do this. Character sizes aren't always the same for different fonts - what looks just right in one font might be too small in another, and too large in yet another.

Comment: It's already done. The application has been around for years and the display framework it's built on doesn't allow setting the font size. So I just don't want our options dialog misleading users into thinking they can customize something they can't.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd like to leave this warning for others that are contemplating the same question. Just curious, has your app always allowed choosing a font with size being fixed, or is this a new capability?

Comment: Sure, it's a reasonable caution for the general case. And this has always been a capability in the program, or at least has for a long time.